# Gson: Flatten redundant object wrap of an array

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have one kind of data from services

- Service A returns:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "id": 333,
  "contact": [
    {
      "type": "phone",
      "number": "12333333"
    },
    {
      "type": "phone",
      "number": "22333333"
    }
  ]
}
```

- I prepared a model class for it:

```
public class People {
    public String name;
    public int id;
    public List<Contact> contact;

    public static class Contact {
        public String type;
        public String number;
    }
    
}
```

- But service B returns:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "id": 333,
  "contact":{
    "entries": [
      {
        "type": "phone",
        "number": "12333333"
      },
      {
        "type": "phone",
        "number": "22333333"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The real situation is there are 10 lists in the json, All list in this JSON is wrapped by a object, then "entries" is the actual list.
I have already use the modal class else where, and I just want to treat them as the same class like:

```
Contact contact = people.contact
```

So any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this with a custom [`TypeAdapterFactory`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) and a [`@JsonAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) annotation on the fields whose value might be wrapped.

The `TypeAdapterFactory` is used to get the delegate adapter (for example `List<Contact>`) and then creates an adapter which unwraps the JSON, if necessary. The `@JsonAdapter` annotation is used to apply this factory only to the affected fields, and not in general to all `List` values.

```java
/**
 * Gson {@link TypeAdapterFactory} which unwraps lists inside JSON objects, if
 * necessary.
 * 
 * <p>Must <b>only</b> be used with {@link JsonAdapter @JsonAdapter}.
 */
public static class WrappedListTypeAdapterFactory implements TypeAdapterFactory {
    // Default constructor to allow Gson to create instances
    public WrappedListTypeAdapterFactory() { }

    @Override
    public <T> TypeAdapter<T> create(Gson gson, TypeToken<T> type) {
        // Get the actual adapter, for example for `List<Contact>`
        // Note: Cannot use Gson.getDelegateAdapter, see https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1028
        TypeAdapter<T> delegate = gson.getAdapter(type);

        return new TypeAdapter<T>() {
            @Override
            public void write(JsonWriter out, T value) throws IOException {
                delegate.write(out, value);
            }

            @Override
            public T read(JsonReader in) throws IOException {
                JsonToken peeked = in.peek();
                if (peeked == JsonToken.NULL) {
                    return null;
                } else if (peeked == JsonToken.BEGIN_ARRAY) {
                    // JSON array is not wrapped, read it directly
                    return delegate.read(in);
                }

                // Start unwrapping the JSON array
                in.beginObject();
                String propertyName = in.nextName();
                if (!propertyName.equals("entries")) {
                    // Don't include property name to avoid log injection attacks
                    throw new JsonParseException("Unexpected property name");
                }

                // Now read the JSON array
                T value = delegate.read(in);
                in.endObject();

                return value;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

```java
public class People {
    public String name;
    public int id;

    @JsonAdapter(WrappedListTypeAdapterFactory.class)
    public List<Contact> contact;

    public static class Contact {
        public String type;
        public String number;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this example really makes me understand how TypeAdapterFactory works.